# What should be the Conditional Probability?

Tags: probability

There are $k+1$ coins in a box. When flipped, the i'th coin will turn up heads with a probability $i/k$, for i in {$0,1,2 ... k$}. A coin is randomly selected from the box and then repeatedly flipped. If first n flips all result in heads, find the conditional probability that the $(n+1)$'st flip will also result in heads.

I have thought of the following two approaches, but unable to determine which is correct.

Let $F_n$ be the event of getting n heads in a row and $E_i$ be the event of choosing the i'th coin. Now,

$1$. $P(F_n)=\sum_{i=0}^k P(F_n|E_i)P(E_i)$

Now, $P(E_i)=\frac{1}{k+1}$ for all i.

Hence, $P(F_n)=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{i^n}{k^n} $

Now, we need to find $$P(F_{n+1}|F_n)=\frac{P(F_{n+1}F_n)}{P(F_n)}$$

$$=\frac{P(F_{n+1})}{P(F_n)}$$

$$=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{i^{n+1}}{k^{n+1}}}{\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{i^n}{k^n}}$$

$2$. Note that we are choosing the coin only once at the start, hence when we find probability of $F_{n+1}$ given $F_n$ we must not consider possibilities for all the points, we must consider only for that coin which we had taken for $F_n$. Therefore,
$$P(F_{n+1}|F_n)=\sum_{i=0}^k P((F_{n+1}|(F_nE_i))P(E_i)$$
$$=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{\frac{i^{n+1}}{k^{n+1}}}{\frac{i^n}{k^n}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{i}{k}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

Which of the above two approaches is correct?

Thanks. :)

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please check edit.

Comment: $P((F_{n+1}|E_i)|(F_n|E_i))$ does not make any sense. There can only be one conditional divider in the function.  I suspect you mean $P(F_{n+1}\mid E_i, F_n)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define what you know.  You have these events:

- Those of selecting the coin: $Y=i$ for $i\in\{0,..,k\}$
- That of obtaining a streak of $n$ heads: $F$
- That of obtaining one more head : $E$

  - $E \perp F \mid Y=i$ ... The flips are conditionally independent for a given coin.

So what probabilities can you immediately evaluate?

You are looking for $\mathsf P(E\mid F)$.

$$\mathsf P(E\mid F)=\sum_{i=0}^k \mathsf P(E\mid Y=i)\mathsf P(Y=i\mid F)$$

---

[After the OP Edit:] Okay, you have:

- $\mathsf P(Y=i)=1/(k+1)$
- $\mathsf P(E\mid Y=i) = i/k$
- $\mathsf P(F\mid Y=i) = (i/k)^n$

  - $\mathsf P(Y=i\mid F) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(F\mid Y=i)\mathsf P(Y=i)}{\sum_{i=0}^k \mathsf P(F\mid Y=i)\mathsf P(Y=i)}$

Thus:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(E\mid F)~=~&\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^k \mathsf P(E\mid Y=i)\mathsf P(F\mid Y=i)\mathsf P(Y=i)}{\sum_{i=0}^k \mathsf P(F\mid Y=i)\mathsf P(Y=i)} \\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^k i^{n+1}}{k~\sum_{i=0}^k i^n}\end{align}$$

$\Box$

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be similar to my first approach. Could you please elaborate what is wrong with my second approach.

Comment: The application of Law of Total Probability to a Conditional Probability is: $$\mathsf P(A\mid C) = \sum_i \mathsf P(A\mid B_i,C)\,\mathsf P(B_i\color{crimson}{\mid C})$$